# Pull data from large XML file

Tags: xml, csv

I have a large xml file (generated from Groundspeak.com) that holds a lot of information regarding locations in my area.

I want to be able to pull certain parts of that data to a new csv file, example below.

```
<name>Isle of Man</name>
  <desc>Geocache file generated by Groundspeak</desc>
  <author>Groundspeak</author>
  <bounds minlat="54.04725" minlon="-4.81115" maxlat="54.401" maxlon="-4.3105" />
  <wpt lat="54.097833" lon="-4.6537">
    <name>GC1E48M</name>
    <desc>Hunter and Quarry by monstermunch, Traditional Cache (2/3)</desc>
    <url>http://www.geocaching.com/seek/cache_details.aspx?guid=b357a623-25ed-43cc-aad5-9c0029231e0c</url>
    <urlname>Hunter and Quarry</urlname>
    <sym>Geocache</sym>
    <type>Geocache|Traditional Cache</type>
    <groundspeak:cache id="933587" available="True" archived="False" xmlns:groundspeak="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1">
      <groundspeak:name>Hunter and Quarry</groundspeak:name>
      <groundspeak:placed_by>monstermunch</groundspeak:placed_by>
      <groundspeak:owner id="1283947">monstermunch</groundspeak:owner>
      <groundspeak:type>Traditional Cache</groundspeak:type>
      <groundspeak:container>Micro</groundspeak:container>
      <groundspeak:attributes>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="13" inc="0">Available at all times</groundspeak:attribute>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="43" inc="1">Watch for livestock</groundspeak:attribute>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="8" inc="1">Scenic view</groundspeak:attribute>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="7" inc="1">Takes less than an hour</groundspeak:attribute>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="39" inc="1">Thorns</groundspeak:attribute>
        <groundspeak:attribute id="1" inc="1">Dogs</groundspeak:attribute>
      </groundspeak:attributes>
      <groundspeak:difficulty>2</groundspeak:difficulty>
      <groundspeak:terrain>3</groundspeak:terrain>
      <groundspeak:country>Isle of Man</groundspeak:country>
      <groundspeak:state>
      </groundspeak:state>
      <groundspeak:short_description html="True">
      </groundspeak:short_description>
      <groundspeak:long_description html="True">&lt;center&gt;&lt;font size="+2" color="#006600" face=
      "Arial"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Hunter and Quarry&lt;/strong&gt; is a traditional
      cache which takes you on a stroll along a little used
      footpath next to Billown Quarry. After walking through the..
```

All I require out of all of that is the `<wpt lat="54.097833" lon="-4.6537">` and the `<desc>Hunter and Quarry by monstermunch, Traditional Cache (2/3)</desc>`

In this format:

-4.6537,54.097833,Hunter and Quarry

Then saves at a csv file.

Im on a Mac, and have Sublime Text, dont dont really know where to start with this.

Comment: Do you know any programming languages? Are you willing to learn?

Comment: Do you just want to extract a single line of CSV from a whole XML file? Or does a file contain multiple `wpt` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use this XSLT line to get the desired result:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(wpt/@lon,',',wpt/@lat,',',wpt/urlname)" />
```

**Result:**

> -4.6537,54.097833,Hunter and Quarry

---

If you also need to take care of `,` chars in the input, you can use the following named template `CSVencode` (which is a little bit more complicated than the above, simple solution):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- Wrap Element   -->
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:call-template name="CSV_encode">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="wpt/@lon" />
      </xsl:call-template>    
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CSV_encode">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="wpt/@lat" />
      </xsl:call-template>    
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CSV_encode">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="wpt/urlname" />
      </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CSV_encode">
      <xsl:param name="str" />
      <xsl:variable name="str2">
        <xsl:call-template name="Quot_encode">
          <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($str2,',')">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',$str2,'&quot;')" />        
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$str2" />        
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Quot_encode">
      <xsl:param name="str" />
      <xsl:param name="outstr" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($str) = 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$outstr" />        
        </xsl:when>        
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($str,'&quot;')">
          <xsl:call-template name="Quot_encode">
            <xsl:with-param name="str"    select="substring($str,2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="outstr" select="concat($outstr,'&quot;&quot;')" />
          </xsl:call-template> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="Quot_encode">
            <xsl:with-param name="str"    select="substring($str,2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="outstr" select="concat($outstr,substring($str,1,1))" />
          </xsl:call-template>         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if `urlname` contains commas?

Comment: @AlexHall: I extended my answer.

Comment: @zx485 Nice and clean update (no quotes if not needed), but if a csv field is quoted, possible quotes inside that field should be escaped with an extra quote :)  (for example: "24"" monitor, black")

Comment: @Danny_ds: Thanks for noticing, but so far I haven't received any feedback from the author of this question. I'm not even sure he's still reading this, because he didn't even react to my request of making his XML well-formed.

Comment: However, I added the handling of quotes to the XSLT code.